# How to store the same inner structure inside a DynamoDbTable

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a class called Customer, inside I have two fields with the same object.

```
@Value
@Builder
@DynamoDbImmutable(builder = Customer.CustomerBuilder.class)
public class Customer {
@Getter(onMethod_ = @DynamoDbPartitionKey)
String id;

@Getter(onMethod_ = {@DynamoDbFlatten, 
@DynamoDbAttribute("phone")})
Phone phone;

@Getter(onMethod_ = {@DynamoDbFlatten, 
@DynamoDbAttribute("HomePhone")})
Phone homePhone;
```

The phone structure

```
@Value
@Builder
@DynamoDbImmutable(builder = Phone.PhoneBuilder.class)
public class Phone {
String number;
....
```

When I put the item into DynamoDB table it says

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to add an attribute to a mapper that already has one with the same name. [Attribute name: number]
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.StaticImmutableTableSchema.lambda$null$2(StaticImmutableTableSchema.java:184)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1085)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.StaticImmutableTableSchema.lambda$new$3(StaticImmutableTableSchema.java:181)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.StaticImmutableTableSchema.<init>(StaticImmutableTableSchema.java:179)
at software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.StaticImmutableTableSchema.<init>(StaticImmutableTableSchema.java:77)
```

How should I store it, tried to give different name for fields, like through DynamoDbAttribute, but didn't help much

Comment: I assume having `String id;` twice is just a typo, otherwise this would not be valid Java code.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I was playing around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently flattening both `phone` and `homePhone` via `@DynamoDbFlatten` and that moves their constituent attributes (both have `number`) to become top-level attributes. You end up with two top-level attributes named `number`, causing the conflict.

Remove `@DynamoDbFlatten` from both and store `phone` and `homePhone` so they become hierarchical. Or find some other way to make these attribute names unique (e.g. renaming them at the attribute level).